# How to set up Nopcommerce 3.1 in IIS Manager without reinstall nopcommerce

Tags: iis-7, nopcommerce, subdirectory

I want to add Nopcommerce 3.1 in my sub directory
https://mydomain.com/subdirectory and won't affect root project?

In IIS Manager > Sites > mydomain.com 
I need choose Add Application or Add Virtual Directory?

May I know the step to Set up Nopcommerce 3.1 without reinstalling Nopcommerce
I have the database ready

And i try to Add Application under mydomain.com 
When i got to https://mydomain.com/preview it not work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution 
I found the solution by using IIS Manager.

1) Go to IIS Manager run > inetmgr
2) right click the domain in your left hand panel
3) Add Virtual Directory
4) Alias your name (here i put preview)
Physical path your files path 
5) Convert your files to application
Done

If you can't see your website you can try to put at index.html to the sub directory
and manually type in your website

www.domain.com/preview/index.html

if can view your index.html

Go to application pool change the .Net Framework to 4.0

That's all